# Translating English “with” + gerund construction to German

Tags: grammar, english-to-german

What is the most elegant way to translate constructions like the following to German?

> She was born in Kansas *with her parents being born in Washington.*

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of an idiomatic translation that doesn't need an extra (subordinate) sentence. So I suppose you rephrase the parts in italics giving rise to a German translation using a (subordinate) sentence:

> Sie ist/wurde in Kansas geboren, *wobei* ihre Eltern in Washington geboren wurden/sind.
>   Sie ist/wurde in Kansas geboren. *Dabei* wurden/sind ihre Eltern in Washington geboren.
>   Sie ist/wurde in Kansas geboren, *während* ihre Eltern in Washington geboren wurden/sind.
>   (Sie ist/wurde in Kansas geboren, *obwohl* ihre Eltern in Washington geboren wurden/sind.)*
>   ...

<sup>* Formally, the *"with"+gerund* construction is not a concessive one. However with regards to content, a concessive translation seems to be possible.</sup>

Comment: "Wobei" is the best choice. "Obwohl" doesn't really match.

Comment: _wobei_ ist wohl etwas neutraler als _obwohl_, aber der Unterschied zwischen _obwohl_ und _wobei_ kommt mir nicht allzu groß vor.

Comment: Obwohl ist immer ein Gegensatz. Wobei kann auch eine Beiordnung ausdrücken, und ist dann eher wie dabei ...

Comment: Kann die englische Konstruktion (rein schriftlich) Gegensätzlichkeit ausdrücken?

Comment: Spricht irgend etwas gegen _während_?

Comment: oder *wohingegen* (wobei mir *wobei* nicht so zusagt)

Comment: während meint zur gleichen Zeit und ist ggf. irreführend. Wie wäre es mit der Konstruktion: "Sie wurde in Kansas geboren, ihre Eltern hingegen in Washington."

Answer (score 5):

Correct me if my perception of the English sentence is wrong, but I think that

> She was born in Kansas with her parents being born in Washington.

does not carry any extra meaning over

> She was born in Kansas, her parents were born in Washington.

and that the former is only chosen because it seems more fluid.  If so then I would not choose any of the constructions proposed by Chris but simply choose

> Sie ist in Kansas geboren, ihre Eltern in Washington.

because it sounds perfectly fine. (As for „ist geboren“ vs „wurde geboren“, this would probably be a separate question ;)